# Custom post type pagination

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to print out a number of posts from multiple post types. However, I can't seem to implement the pagination - once I go to .../category.../page/2 I get a page not found error. It seems like it doesn't even try to read what's inside of my archive.php file.

I'm 100% sure that there's no problem with permalinks, since I've tried resetting them and etc.

I suppose it has something to do with the fact that in admin settings the number of posts per page is set to 10, but i really need to be able to edit this number dynamically.

I've tried a variaty of fixes from here, but non of them seem to work: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-with-custom-post-type-getting-a-404?replies=1#post-1616810

I'm sorry if it's highly repetitive question - none of other fixes I found worked for me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (not tested):

```
$posts_per_page = 10;
$post_type = 'YOUR_POST_TYPE'

$args = array( 'post_type'=> $post_type, 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') );

query_posts( $args );

// here loop
```